# finding an specific value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, cakephp-3.0

i have an array that i would like to do a search in it and find out if an specific **id** in **answers** array and if it is pass all its values to another array and remove it from the primary array.i tried bunch of loops but they just make my program to run slower.
i also tried :

```
$key = array_search('2', array_column($myarray, 'id'));
```

but then nothing was returned. i also tried collection class in cakephp 3 but that did not helped me.
so i put my array here hopefully someone will help me get throw this. i should mention that im using **cake php 3**

```
\src\Template\Comlibs\get_Result.ctp (line 10)
[
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Comlib) {

    'id' => (int) 1,
    'question' => 'how to kill someone?',
    'answer' => (int) 2,
    'asked' => (int) 90,
    'tags' => 'kill,professional killer',
    'created' => null,
    'modified' => null,
    'answers' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Answer) {

            'id' => (int) 2,
            'question_id' => (int) 1,
            'answer' => 'worst behaviour',
            'rate' => (float) 5,
            'view' => (int) 29,
            'helpful' => '33',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Answers'

        },
        (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Answer) {

            'id' => (int) 3,
            'question_id' => (int) 1,
            'answer' => 'He never luv us',
            'rate' => (float) 8,
            'view' => (int) 60,
            'helpful' => '22',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Answers'

        },
        (int) 2 => object(App\Model\Entity\Answer) {

            'id' => (int) 4,
            'question_id' => (int) 1,
            'answer' => 'that bitch aint a part of me',
            'rate' => (float) 4,
            'view' => (int) 76,
            'helpful' => '75',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Answers'

        },
        (int) 3 => object(App\Model\Entity\Answer) {

            'id' => (int) 5,
            'question_id' => (int) 1,
            'answer' => 'she was so friendly',
            'rate' => (float) 2.5,
            'view' => (int) 21,
            'helpful' => '10',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Answers'

        },
        (int) 4 => object(App\Model\Entity\Answer) {

            'id' => (int) 6,
            'question_id' => (int) 1,
            'answer' => 'the old movie',
            'rate' => (float) 3.2,
            'view' => (int) 11,
            'helpful' => '11',
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Answers'

        }
    ],
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Comlibs'

}
]
```

tnx in advanced

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Collection of **Cakephp**, you have to use the match method of collection

```
use Cake\Collection\Collection;
$collection = new Collection($data['answers']);
$answer = $collection->match(['answers.id' => 2]);
```

[Collection::match](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::match)

Comment: when i use $data['answers'] it says : Only an array or \Traversable is allowed for Collection, BUT when i use only $data there is no error, i did each for  $collection and what i got is an array without my 2nd array that is ID=2, now how can i use this new collection ( $answer ) cause when i used each it was empty and toArray() shows an empty array